# Why is @media (max-device-width: 360px) affected by the @media (max-device-width: 1024px)?

Tags: html, css

Just curious why one of the "media size" is affected by the bigger "bigger media size"?
I have more code but where thing else works but these two.

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 360px){
 .contact_center_image{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20%;
  bottom: 50px;  
 }
 .image_size{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
 }
}



@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){
 .contact_center_image{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 23%;
  bottom: 50px;  
 }
 .image_size{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 700px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact_center_image">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Image" class="image_size">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS stands for "Cascading Style Sheets", meaning there is a vertical hierarchy. Your lower code takes dominance when both rules apply, and in this case, a screen size less than 360px is also less than 1024px. If you want the 360px rule to have greater priority, you need to move it below the 1024px snippet.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){
    .contact_center_image{
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 23%;
        bottom: 50px;       
    }
    .image_size{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 700px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 360px){
    .contact_center_image{
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 20%;
        bottom: 50px;       
    }
    .image_size{
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: While you can have multiple rules Cascading over each other, this will cause a lot of style rule repetitions and you'd need to update multiple @media statements to make a change propergate through all of these cascades.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I was using google devtool and those where the devices it was testing for.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){
```

This conditional will return **`true`** for any device width size up to and including the spacified value.

So think of it as:

```
@media only screen and (any-device-width-up-to-1024+1px){
```

Therefore 360px width is less than 1024px width so both your `@media` rules will be applied.

Try using `min-device-width` rules instead, or a combination of both `max-` and `min-` for each `@media` scope.

While you can have multiple rules *Cascading* over each other (when both apply, the last one is applied last), this will cause a lot of style repetitions and you'd need to update multiple `@media` statements to make a change propergate through these cascades.

## Example Tweak:

Below, the first rule will apply to widths of 361 up to 1024 the second will apply to widths from 0 up to 360.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)
                   and (min-device-width: 361px) {
    .contact_center_image{
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 23%;
        bottom: 50px;       
    }
    .image_size{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 700px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 360px){
    .contact_center_image{
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 20%;
        bottom: 50px;       
    }
    .image_size{
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only question where did you learn about that so I can read up on it more.

Comment: @JasonWest haha, I might have actually learnt to use it from Stack Overflow. However there are many, many online guides for CSS ( search for CSS3 as `@media` is part of that)

Comment: @JasonWest I've not checked these but [these links](https://www.google.com/search?q=best+way+to+learn+CSS3&oq=best+way+to+learn+CSS3) would be a good start. Good luck!